# How to show decimal percentage in pie charts using iReport Designer?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, pie-chart

I have a *pie chart* in my report. I've set the Legend label format to `{0}` and the label format to `{2}`. I need the percentage to be decimal, but I don't know what I have to do?

It would be great if someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Chance.

Two solutions possible:

1) Create a chart customizer: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/539659/how-show-percentage-decimal-value-pie-chart

2) Query the percentage with the data from your datasource (or calculate in a variable), then use the label expression instead of label format

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iReport there is a lableFormat and legendLabelFormat properties in the pie plot set of properties (in the property sheet).

Set the format to:

{0} {2}

This is a special syntax for labels where the {n} placeholders have that meaning:

{0} is the key (usually used as lable)

{1} is the value

{2} is the percentage